# Constructing an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL and PL/SQL.

I have a table with a single column "name".  The data in this column is a semicolon separated string.  I want to count the number of elements in each row.

For example, if there are two rows in the table, one with the string 'smith;black;tiger'and one with the string 'x;y', I want the result of the query to be 3 for the first row and 2 for the second row.

How can I write a SQL query that will count the number of elements in a separated list of values?

Comment: CSV in a database column is a very bad idea. It is not normalized, it is slow, you cannot use indexes and joins are a pain. Never do it.

Comment: What's your database platform?

Comment: You don't have "first row" in database table.  Ordering is never guaranteed.

Comment: The answer is to count the number of ";" separates + 1 in each row.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very hard to understand, but I think you are saying that you have a table with a column "name", and inside that column, each cell contains multiple values separated by semicolons. You want to count the number of semicolon-separated values in each row.

The [PLSQL string functions](http://psoug.org/reference/string_func.html) could help you here, but really you are talking about writing program code to do this task (this isn't normally the job for a database query language). For example, you could use [this trick](http://psoug.org/reference/translate_replace.html) to count the number of semicolons, and then add one:

```
LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(TRANSLATE(name,'x;','x')) + 1
```

But the point @Johan is making is that this is a bad way to structure your data. For example, it makes it impossible to lookup by name properly. You can't say `where name == "smith"`, because the name doesn't equal `"smith"`, it equals `"smith;black;tiger"`. You'll have to do a substring search, saying `where name like "smith"`, and that will be inefficient and wrong. What if I ask to look up the name "smi"? You'll say `where name like "smi"` which will incorrectly find that result -- there is no way to say that "smith" is in the table but "smi" is not, because both are substrings of "smith;black;tiger".

A much better solution, if you want an entry to have multiple names, is to give the entry a unique ID; say 123. (You can ask SQL to automatically generate unique IDs for table rows.) Then, have a separate table for names which maps back onto that row. So say you gave the "smith;black;tiger" row the ID 123 and the "x;y" row the ID 124. Now you would have another table `NameMap` with two columns:

```
name    |  entry
------------------
smith   |   123
black   |   123
tiger   |   123
x       |   124
y       |   124
```

Now you can look up names in that table and map them onto the name entries table with a join.

And you'll be able to answer your question: "how many names correspond to each row of the entry table" with a [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement like this:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as value_count FROM NameMap GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 4):

You can hack this using this code

**SQL code horror**

```
SELECT name
       ,(LENGTH(COALESCE(vals,'')) 
        - LENGTH(TRANSLATE(COALESCE(vals,''), ';',''))) + 1 AS value_count
FROM table1
ORDER BY name
```

**Remarks**
CSV in a database is a very bad anti-pattern.
`VALUES` is a reserved word, it's a bad idea to name a column after a reserved word.